# Customise checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woothemes

I am working with wordpress. I want to make custom payment integration in chckout page in woocommerce. I need to use **eMerchecahntBroker** api in checkout page. So how can I customise it?

I have download api.php file of merchant broker and put it into theme directory.

api.php file contain below code.

```
<?

 define("APPROVED", 1);
 define("DECLINED", 2);
 define("ERROR", 3);

 class gwapi
 {

// Initial Setting Functions

function setLogin($username, $password)
{
/*{{{*/
    $this->login['username'] = $username;
    $this->login['password'] = $password;
}/*}}}*/

function setOrder(
    $orderid,
    $orderdescription,
    $tax,
    $shipping,
    $ponumber,
    $ipaddress
  ) {/*{{{*/
    $this->order['orderid']          = $orderid;
    $this->order['orderdescription'] = $orderdescription;
    $this->order['tax']              = $tax;
    $this->order['shipping']         = $shipping;
    $this->order['ponumber']         = $ponumber;
    $this->order['ipaddress']        = $ipaddress;
}/*}}}*/

 function setBilling(
    $firstname,
    $lastname,
    $company,
    $address1,
    $address2,
    $city,
    $state,
    $zip,
    $country,
    $phone,
    $fax,
    $email,
    $website
  ) {/*{{{*/
    $this->billing['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $this->billing['lastname']  = $lastname;
    $this->billing['company']   = $company;
    $this->billing['address1']  = $address1;
    $this->billing['address2']  = $address2;
    $this->billing['city']      = $city;
    $this->billing['state']     = $state;
    $this->billing['zip']       = $zip;
    $this->billing['country']   = $country;
    $this->billing['phone']     = $phone;
    $this->billing['fax']       = $fax;
    $this->billing['email']     = $email;
    $this->billing['website']   = $website;
  }/*}}}*/

function setShipping(
    $firstname,
    $lastname,
    $company,
    $address1,
    $address2,
    $city,
    $state,
    $zip,
    $country,
    $email
) {/*{{{*/
    $this->shipping['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $this->shipping['lastname']  = $lastname;
    $this->shipping['company']   = $company;
    $this->shipping['address1']  = $address1;
    $this->shipping['address2']  = $address2;
    $this->shipping['city']      = $city;
    $this->shipping['state']     = $state;
    $this->shipping['zip']       = $zip;
    $this->shipping['country']   = $country;
    $this->shipping['email']     = $email;
}/*}}}*/

// Transaction Functions

   function doSale($amount, $ccnumber, $ccexp, $cvv = "")
   {
   /*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Sales Information
    $query .= "ccnumber=" . urlencode($ccnumber) . "&";
    $query .= "ccexp=" . urlencode($ccexp) . "&";
    $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "cvv=" . urlencode($cvv) . "&";
    // Order Information
    $query .= "ipaddress=" . urlencode($this->order['ipaddress']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderid=" . urlencode($this->order['orderid']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderdescription=" . urlencode($this->order['orderdescription']) . "&";
    $query .= "tax=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['tax'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['shipping'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "ponumber=" . urlencode($this->order['ponumber']) . "&";
    // Billing Information
    $query .= "firstname=" . urlencode($this->billing['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "lastname=" . urlencode($this->billing['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "company=" . urlencode($this->billing['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "address1=" . urlencode($this->billing['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "address2=" . urlencode($this->billing['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "city=" . urlencode($this->billing['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "state=" . urlencode($this->billing['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "zip=" . urlencode($this->billing['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "country=" . urlencode($this->billing['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "phone=" . urlencode($this->billing['phone']) . "&";
    $query .= "fax=" . urlencode($this->billing['fax']) . "&";
    $query .= "email=" . urlencode($this->billing['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "website=" . urlencode($this->billing['website']) . "&";
    // Shipping Information
    $query .= "shipping_firstname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_lastname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_company=" . urlencode($this->shipping['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address1=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address2=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_city=" . urlencode($this->shipping['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_state=" . urlencode($this->shipping['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_zip=" . urlencode($this->shipping['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_country=" . urlencode($this->shipping['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_email=" . urlencode($this->shipping['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "type=sale";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doAuth($amount, $ccnumber, $ccexp, $cvv = "")
{
 /*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Sales Information
    $query .= "ccnumber=" . urlencode($ccnumber) . "&";
    $query .= "ccexp=" . urlencode($ccexp) . "&";
    $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "cvv=" . urlencode($cvv) . "&";
    // Order Information
    $query .= "ipaddress=" . urlencode($this->order['ipaddress']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderid=" . urlencode($this->order['orderid']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderdescription=" . urlencode($this->order['orderdescription']) . "&";
    $query .= "tax=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['tax'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['shipping'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "ponumber=" . urlencode($this->order['ponumber']) . "&";
    // Billing Information
    $query .= "firstname=" . urlencode($this->billing['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "lastname=" . urlencode($this->billing['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "company=" . urlencode($this->billing['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "address1=" . urlencode($this->billing['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "address2=" . urlencode($this->billing['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "city=" . urlencode($this->billing['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "state=" . urlencode($this->billing['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "zip=" . urlencode($this->billing['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "country=" . urlencode($this->billing['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "phone=" . urlencode($this->billing['phone']) . "&";
    $query .= "fax=" . urlencode($this->billing['fax']) . "&";
    $query .= "email=" . urlencode($this->billing['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "website=" . urlencode($this->billing['website']) . "&";
    // Shipping Information
    $query .= "shipping_firstname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_lastname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_company=" . urlencode($this->shipping['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address1=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address2=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_city=" . urlencode($this->shipping['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_state=" . urlencode($this->shipping['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_zip=" . urlencode($this->shipping['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_country=" . urlencode($this->shipping['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_email=" . urlencode($this->shipping['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "type=auth";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doCredit($amount, $ccnumber, $ccexp)
{
/*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Sales Information
    $query .= "ccnumber=" . urlencode($ccnumber) . "&";
    $query .= "ccexp=" . urlencode($ccexp) . "&";
    $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    // Order Information
    $query .= "ipaddress=" . urlencode($this->order['ipaddress']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderid=" . urlencode($this->order['orderid']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderdescription=" . urlencode($this->order['orderdescription']) . "&";
    $query .= "tax=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['tax'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['shipping'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "ponumber=" . urlencode($this->order['ponumber']) . "&";
    // Billing Information
    $query .= "firstname=" . urlencode($this->billing['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "lastname=" . urlencode($this->billing['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "company=" . urlencode($this->billing['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "address1=" . urlencode($this->billing['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "address2=" . urlencode($this->billing['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "city=" . urlencode($this->billing['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "state=" . urlencode($this->billing['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "zip=" . urlencode($this->billing['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "country=" . urlencode($this->billing['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "phone=" . urlencode($this->billing['phone']) . "&";
    $query .= "fax=" . urlencode($this->billing['fax']) . "&";
    $query .= "email=" . urlencode($this->billing['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "website=" . urlencode($this->billing['website']) . "&";
    $query .= "type=credit";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doOffline($authorizationcode, $amount, $ccnumber, $ccexp)
{
/*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Sales Information
    $query .= "ccnumber=" . urlencode($ccnumber) . "&";
    $query .= "ccexp=" . urlencode($ccexp) . "&";
    $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "authorizationcode=" . urlencode($authorizationcode) . "&";
    // Order Information
    $query .= "ipaddress=" . urlencode($this->order['ipaddress']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderid=" . urlencode($this->order['orderid']) . "&";
    $query .= "orderdescription=" . urlencode($this->order['orderdescription']) . "&";
    $query .= "tax=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['tax'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping=" . urlencode(number_format($this->order['shipping'], 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    $query .= "ponumber=" . urlencode($this->order['ponumber']) . "&";
    // Billing Information
    $query .= "firstname=" . urlencode($this->billing['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "lastname=" . urlencode($this->billing['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "company=" . urlencode($this->billing['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "address1=" . urlencode($this->billing['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "address2=" . urlencode($this->billing['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "city=" . urlencode($this->billing['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "state=" . urlencode($this->billing['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "zip=" . urlencode($this->billing['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "country=" . urlencode($this->billing['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "phone=" . urlencode($this->billing['phone']) . "&";
    $query .= "fax=" . urlencode($this->billing['fax']) . "&";
    $query .= "email=" . urlencode($this->billing['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "website=" . urlencode($this->billing['website']) . "&";
    // Shipping Information
    $query .= "shipping_firstname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['firstname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_lastname=" . urlencode($this->shipping['lastname']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_company=" . urlencode($this->shipping['company']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address1=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address1']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_address2=" . urlencode($this->shipping['address2']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_city=" . urlencode($this->shipping['city']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_state=" . urlencode($this->shipping['state']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_zip=" . urlencode($this->shipping['zip']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_country=" . urlencode($this->shipping['country']) . "&";
    $query .= "shipping_email=" . urlencode($this->shipping['email']) . "&";
    $query .= "type=offline";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doCapture($transactionid, $amount = 0)
{
/*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Transaction Information
    $query .= "transactionid=" . urlencode($transactionid) . "&";
    if ($amount>0) {
        $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    }
    $query .= "type=capture";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doVoid($transactionid)
{
/*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Transaction Information
    $query .= "transactionid=" . urlencode($transactionid) . "&";
    $query .= "type=void";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function doRefund($transactionid, $amount = 0)
{
/*{{{*/

    $query  = "";
    // Login Information
    $query .= "username=" . urlencode($this->login['username']) . "&";
    $query .= "password=" . urlencode($this->login['password']) . "&";
    // Transaction Information
    $query .= "transactionid=" . urlencode($transactionid) . "&";
    if ($amount>0) {
        $query .= "amount=" . urlencode(number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")) . "&";
    }
    $query .= "type=refund";
    return $this->_doPost($query);

}/*}}}*/

function _doPost($query)
{
/*{{{*/
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.embgateway.com/api/transact.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if (!($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
    print "\n$data\n";
    $data = explode("&", $data);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
        $rdata = explode("=", $data[$i]);
        $this->responses[$rdata[0]] = $rdata[1];
    }
    return $this->responses['response'];
  }/*}}}*/
  }

  $gw = new gwapi;
  $gw->setLogin("demo", "password");
  $gw->setBilling(
"John",
"Smith",
"Acme, Inc.",
"123 Main St",
"Suite 200",
"Beverly Hills",
"CA",
"90210",
"US",
"555-555-5555",
"555-555-5556",
"support@example.com",
"www.example.com"
);
$gw->setShipping(
"Mary",
"Smith",
"na",
"124 Shipping Main St",
"Suite Ship",
"Beverly Hills",
"CA",
"90210",
"US",
"support@example.com"
 );
$gw->setOrder("1234", "Big Order", 1, 2, "PO1234", "65.192.14.10");

$r = $gw->doSale("50.00", "4111111111111111", "1010");
print $gw->responses['responsetext'];
```

Now, How can I use this script in checkout page?

Comment: Can you explain do you want to customize customize checkout form?

Comment: Yes, i want to customize it.

Comment: so why you integrate API you have to customize checkout form.There is no need to customize API

Comment: @OwaisAlam I mean i have used woocommerce checkout form not custom form.Then i have pass all value to the order page where i have include this api.php file.